# Solutions of an ODE when the function is continuous but not a lipschitz function.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

$$x' = 1+x^{2/3}  \\
x(0) = 0$$

Does this differential equation have infinite solutions since it doesn't satisfy lipschitz condition? Is the solution set similar in shape to $x' = x^{2/3}$ with its characteristic paintbrush shape?
Is there any analytic solution for the differential equation after separating variables? I'm stuck with $3(x+\arctan(x)) = t$

Answer (score 0):

In this case the solution is unique and globally defined.
If you consider the (strictly increasing) function
$$
F(x) := \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+s^{2/3}}\, ds = 3(\sqrt[3]{x} - \arctan \sqrt[3]{x}),
\qquad
x\in\mathbb{R},
$$
then the solution is implicitly defined by
$$
F(x) = t,
$$
i.e.
$$
x(t) = F^{-1}(t), \qquad t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, an initial value problem of the form
$$
x'=f(x), \quad x(t_0)=x_0,
$$
where $f$ is continuous and positive for all $x\in\mathbb R$ (or positive for all $x\in\mathbb R$), then it enjoys global uniqueness.

Justification. Setting, 
$$
F(x)=\int_{x_0}^x\frac{dw}{f(w)},
$$
one observes that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}F(x)=\frac{x'}{f(x)}=1,
$$
and hence $F\big(x(t)\big)=t-t_0$ and finally
$$
x(t)=F^{-1}(t-t_0).
$$
This provides UNIQUENESS. Note that $F$ has an inverse as $F'>0$.